# Within a stored-procedure the value of a field returned from a select query cannot recognized

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im `mySQL` I have the following `stored procedure`. Inside the sp I have a `select` query and then the dt value is being used in the `if clause`.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`cefcy`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_checkup`(IN `p_id` INT(11), IN `u_id`INT(11),  IN `v_id` INT(11) )
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    SELECT max(id) as ver_id, max(dt) as dt FROM ps_versioning as ps_v where ps_v.patient_id= p_id and ps_v.user_id = u_id;
    IF (DATE(dt)=CURDATE()) THEN
        INSERT INTO `endorse_checkup` (`patient_id`, `checkup_date`, `status`, `version_id`) VALUES (p_id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() , 1, v_id );
    END IF;
    END
```

However, when I'm trying to call it, I get the message: `Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'dt' in 'field list'`

Comment: Alias != variable!!!

Comment: @Akina OK, thanks. Do you have a suggestion of how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If edit your procedure "as is", then

```
CREATE 
DEFINER=`cefcy`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `insert_checkup`(IN `p_id` INT(11), IN `u_id`INT(11),  IN `v_id` INT(11) )
NO SQL
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(id), MAX(dt) INTO @ver_id, @dt 
    FROM ps_versioning as ps_v 
    WHERE ps_v.patient_id= p_id 
      AND ps_v.user_id = u_id;
    IF (DATE(@dt)=CURDATE()) THEN
        INSERT INTO `endorse_checkup` (`patient_id`, `checkup_date`, `status`, `version_id`) 
        VALUES (p_id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() , 1, v_id );
    END IF;
END
```

But it is unclear what's the aim to select `MAX(id)` which is not used later...

Comment: Thank you very much! That's it. MAX(id) is actually used. I haven't copied all the script of the `stored-procedure`.

Comment: @zinon One more - the `NO SQL` option is INCORRECT. You MUST replace it with `MODIFIES SQL DATA`.

Comment: It is better to use local variables declared with (`DECLARE v_var datatype)` inside stored procedures instead of user-defined (`@var´) variables. The benefit is that the local variables have defined datatypes and one avoids errors that might happen when a procedure calls another procedure/function and they happen to use same variable. Also, as user-defined variables keep their value throughout the connection, they might have a value already set.

Comment: @slaakso I used UDV because if `MAX(id)` was unnecessary, the procedure text would be simplified to a single-statement form without using variables at all.

Comment: @Akina If the procedure does not use variables at all, then that is fine ;). If it does use variables, it's better to use the local variabkles. Someone might call the procedure and happen to use `@dt` in their code and have trouble because of that.

Comment: @slaakso That's everything true, I'm not arguing.